# Error when changing WHERE parameters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a query on SQL Server that is working but when i change the where parameters i receive an error.

"Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation."

The below query works when the day is -7. If i change this to -90 I receive the error.
Can anyone let me know why and what I need to do to correct this?

```
SELECT 
Category,
Count(Category) AS TotalTasks,
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN impact > 0 then 1 end),0) AS TaskCompleted,
    (SELECT ISNULL(CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN impact > 0 then 1 end)AS decimal(5,2))/CAST(Count(Category) AS decimal(5,2)),0)) AS Ratio
FROM AppTasks
WHERE   TimeRaised > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE()) 
GROUP BY Category
```

Thanks

Comment: What datatype is your TimeRaised column? Is it by any chance a string and you have in it values you aren't supposed to have? Or possibly in your other columns from the `ISNULL(SUM(CASE` etc. part? That's where I'd start digging into. Just do a `SELECT category, impact FROM AppTask WHERE TimeRaised > DATEADD(day, -7, getdate())`, then replace with `-90` and if you get the same error then the problem is with your TimeRaised column. Otherwise it's with some incorrect values in either your `Category` or `Impact` columns.

Comment: TimeRaised is datetime, null. I have looked and there are no invalid fields in the TimeRaised column.

Comment: then check the values in the `Category` or `Impact` columns, where you're applying the `CAST()`

Comment: I was thinking it could be something in the impact field as this is a tinyint and i have added a statement which would make a result a decimal where i have names the column Ratio

Comment: Impact fields there are null values but the rest all all numbers but its thought i had worked around this with the ISNULL statement.

Comment: the `ISNULL()` is way too far "outside", I believe you should use `ISNULL(Impact)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `ISNULL` on your `CASE` you could handle this with an `ELSE`. Your error is coming from the fact that your `COUNT(Category)` or `SUM((CASE WHEN impact > 0 then 1 end))` is returning a value that is larger than 999. When you are casting this as `cast(... as decimal(5,2))` you are specifying a precision of 2, which only leaves room for 3 digits to the left of the decimal. i.e. the max value would be `999.99`.

**EXAMPLE**

```
select cast(1000 as decimal(5,2))
```

I assume you are casting because you want to use numeric division versus integer division to avoid only getting whole numbers as a result. Thus, just multiply by 1.0 and remove all casting. Note, you only need the numerator **or** the denominator to be a decimal.

```
(SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN impact > 0 then 1 else 0 end)
    / 
    (Count(Category) * 1.0)
) AS Ratio
```